# How to handle invalid routes without slash in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, dropbox-api

At the moment, I handle invalid routes in Ember.js like this:

```
this.route('invalid', { path: '*path' }
```

This works and applies to routes like:

```
https://www.appname.com/#/misspelled_name
```

However, when using Dropbox Datastores API, I am having some problems. After an authentication request, Dropbox redirects me to:

```
https://www.appname.com/#access_token=...
```

Is there a way to handle this route? Without the slash before the route name? In this case, the 'invalid' route is not applied and I receive an error 'The route access_token=... was not found'. How should I handle this response in Ember?

**UPDATE**

I don't think it is possible to handle this. The only working solution for me was to do authentication before Ember was even loaded. After successful authentication, I load my ember app:

```
   window.dropboxClient = new Dropbox.Client({
      key: 'some_key'
    });

    dropboxClient.authenticate({ interactive: true }, function(error) {
      if (error) {
        return console.log('Error during authentication');
      }
    });

    yepnope([{
      test : window.dropboxClient.isAuthenticated(),
      yep  : ['my-ember-app.js']
    }])
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I have the same problem with facebook authentication redirect url having `#_=_`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have direct experience with EmberJS, but one possibility might be to run `client.authenticate({ interactive: false });` before the EmberJS script is even loaded.

Another alternative is to specify a different redirect URI (not the same page as the rest of your app) and not load EmberJS on that page. (That page would then presumably redirect back to the main app when it was done.) You could also forgo redirects altogether and use the pop-up auth driver instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however, I need to do it inside Ember. It is a vital part of the application.

Maybe the pop-up auth will solve this. I will try it, thanks...

Comment: Both cases are pretty much the same... you'll need to use an OAuth redirect page that does *not* have Ember running on it. That can either appear briefly in a pop-up or briefly before redirecting back to your main page. Which one you prefer should just be about whether you like the pop-up flow better than the redirect flow.

Answer (score 0):

Before the `#/`, you aren't actually inside of the ember app.  As a result, none of the ember code will have any impact on this.

Comment: That's not exactly true. EmberJs tries to deal with all routes and will throw an exception like this one: `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The route _=_ was not found` . This one is for facebook authentication redirect with similar issue.